# Is it possible to know the progress of a put operation of ydn-db?

Tags: ydn-db

Since the initial filling of tables into indexedDb via ydn-db's `db.put` takes quite long depending on data amount i want to present the user with a progress bar.

Is it possible to know the progess of a `db.put` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not and not likely to implement that feature. If number of records is too large, it is recommended to use smaller by batch size.

See [this sample code](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/usage/transaction.html) for populating large CSV file to ydn-db.

You can see example implementation of progress bar in [full text search app](http://yathit.github.io/ydndb-demo/ydn-db-text/animals/animals.html) during loading data. This loading happen only for the first time of visiting the page.